# CXF 2.7.7 org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unexpected element

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I am experiencing an error I cannot understand since upgrading to CXF 2.7.7. When making a web service call CXF is reporting this exception:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: 
Unexpected element {http://schema.myorg.com/GetReference/}ReferenceResponse found.
Expected {http://services.myorg.com/}getReferences
```

This makes no sense, because ReferenceResponse is exactly the response I expect. The name getReferences appears to refer to the name of the @WebMethod annotated method that is being called. The return type of this method is ReferenceResponse.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, I encountered this problem and did you resolved this problem and is there any update? thanks in advance.

Comment: @LeoHuang I have now posted an answer explaining what I did

Comment: Thank you very much, actually I generate all the client code by using `cxf-codegen-plugin`, and all the method signature are generated automatically, so it is not make sense.

Answer (score 4):

I never found a truly satisfactory answer to this, but, it was solved when I replaced the existing client interface with one generated by wsdl2cxf. This also involved migrating from Xbeans to JAXB for marshaling, which may have had something to do with it.

However, in the interim adding the following annotation to the interface prevented the error.

```
@EndpointProperty(key = "soap.no.validate.parts", value = "true")
```

Comment: Hi rjsang, I resolve the problem by debug into the cxf source code, basically this exception is thrown in DocLiteralInInterceptor, and sometimes is caused by the response are not valid like not literal document, or not a valid soap message.

Comment: Thanks for this post, it was helpful.  I will add to it if you are also generating the interfaces like I am, and you don't want to have to keep editing the interfaces on each regeneration, you can do this inline wherever you are using the port: port.getRequestContext().put("soap.no.validate.parts", "true");

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue when found that my SOAPLoggingHandler by default returns **false** in its methods. It should be changed to **true**:

```
public class SOAPLoggingHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        SOAPMessage message= context.getMessage();
        boolean isOutboundMessage = (Boolean)context.get (MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if(isOutboundMessage){
            System.out.println("OUTBOUND MESSAGE\n");

        }else{
            System.out.println("INBOUND MESSAGE\n");
        }
        try {
            message.writeTo(System.out);
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        SOAPMessage message= context.getMessage();
        try {
            message.writeTo(System.out);
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen by adding a custom http header in my app code, specifically http keep alive. The ws client http was reused and it looks like cxf was not reseting the soap action header on subsequent calls.